# Use different googleservices of different projects in single app android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

In my application i have different productFlavors(DEV, DEMO,PROD) and each productFlavors has debug and release modes.

As i need to use different values for remote config, i have **created 2 projects, one for Prod, another one QA**. Now i have 2 different google services.json file.

**I tried to keep json file in my app and run app, but app is always expecting json file in app folder and if keep one in app folder and another one at flavor folder is is not picking flavor json and always taking app json file.**

```
buildTypes {
        release {

        }

        debug {

        }
    }

    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "client", "server"
    productFlavors {
        Customer1 {
            dimension "client"
        }
        Customer2 {
            dimension "client"
        }
        DEV {
            dimension "server"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        DEMO {
            dimension "server"
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        }
        PROD {
            dimension "server"
        }
        QA {
            dimension "server"
            applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        }
    }
```

Any help on this?

Comment: You don't have to use the gradle plugin and the JSON config.  You can just take full control over the config yourself by adding per-flavor XML resources.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you please suggest on xml approach?. I have tried that, but it still takes from app json file